# how to insert the labels selected to checkbox into textarea using jquery?

Tags: jquery, symfony

I'm working  this code

```
("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each(function() {
   var test = $("label[for='"+$(this).attr('id')+"']").text();
   $("textarea#MyTextArea")...... //i need help me here, please

});
```

Comment: please note that `textarea#MyTextArea` should only be `#MyTextArea` as ids should be unique and the selector textarea is unnecessary and slows things down significantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each(function() {
   var test = $("label[for='"+$(this).attr('id')+"']").text();
   $("textarea#MyTextArea").append(test);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your textarea `id` is correct, you need:

```
$("textarea#MyTextArea").val(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
    var text = $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text();
    $("#MyTextArea").val( function( _, val ) {return val + ' ' + text;});
});
```

- Loop through all the `checked` checkboxes first.
- Then get the label for that checkbox.
- Set the `textarea` value to that text.
- Also, since **ID**'s are supposed to be unique no need to do this `$("textarea#MyTextArea")`. You can just call it like `$("#MyTextArea")`.